# How do I use accented characters in the window title in SDL2?

Tags: c++, sdl

```
SDL_Window* window = SDL_CreateWindow(
    "Capítulo 1",
    SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED,
    SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED,
    640,
    480,
    SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN
);
```

The displayed title is Cap?tulo 1

Comment: You should verify if your source file (.c or .cpp) was edited/saved in unicode UTF-8 format.

Comment: in addition to what @tunglt said make sure your compiler is using the correct encoding as well. You may want to add these details to the question.

Answer (score 0):

I run into the same problem in Windows with Japanese letters.

Using UTF-8 string literals works for me:

```cpp
SDL_Window* window = SDL_CreateWindow(
    u8"Capítulo 1",
    SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED,
    SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED,
    640,
    480,
    SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN
);
```