# How to add non-english characters on a screen title in pygame?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I wanted to make a program with some cyrillic text in it. I made this code that would open up a window, have a title in Russian, and would put some Russian text (meaning Rasputin) on screen.The cyrillic font file supports cyrillic text.

```
import pygame as pg

pg.init()
pg.font.init()
font = pg.font.Font("Cyrillic-font.ttf",24)
gameDisplay = pg.display.set_mode((600, 400))
pg.display.set_caption("Распутин")


gameExit = False

while not gameExit:
    for event in pg.event.get():
        if event.type == pg.QUIT:
             gameExit = True
    gameDisplay.fill((255,255,255))
    text = font.render("Распутин",True,(255,0,0))
    gameDisplay.blit(text,(200,200)) 
    pg.display.update()
quit()
```

The program will display the text onto the screen. However, in the title, all that appears is "????????". I've attempted to use the `font.render` into the `pg.display.set_caption()`, but that wouldn't work as `font.render` gives a pygame surface instead of a string, so the code would stop.

Comment: It works for me with Ubuntu 18.10 - could it be the font used for the titlebar theme?

Comment: This problem also occurs for me on Windows 10, however I can change other title bars (e.g. command prompt `title Распутин`).

Comment: @Kingsley It's most likely to be the problem, seeing that I have to use a special font to display the text onto the screen. Unfortunately I haven't figured out how to edit the font of the titlebar in pygame.

Comment: @OranjeMaan - I wondered if it was an encoding issue?  Is that text "Распутин" encoded in UTF-8 (or unicode), or some other code-page?  I came across a Japanese font the other day where the hiragana glyphs were mapped on latin A-Z, as opposed to wherever they should normally be indexed.  Did you add the correct encoding header to python, e.g.: `# coding: utf-8` (must be 1st or 2nd line) - see http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ for details

Comment: @Kingsley I have checked the font file, as it also supported Latin characters along with some characters of other languages, the glyphs should be in their normal index. I didn't have an encoding header put in before. After adding one though, nothing has changed.

Comment: @Eric it seems to work for me as well if I do so. It seems the title in the command prompt and the title in the window pygame brings up should be using the same font. Thus, I have now realized the problem is unlikely the font being unable to display the message.

Comment: This might be a limitation of SDL on Windows. A possible solution is to remove the default title bar with `pygame.NOFRAME` implement it yourself.

Comment: [Related SDL question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53741550/how-do-i-use-accented-characters-in-the-window-title-in-sdl2)

Answer (score -1):

In my opinion, it is an operative system design failure.

In windows 10 Pro I just changed "Region Settings" to Russian. Find it in "Region, Administrative". All keep old language and text Russian text has Cyrillic letters.

Maybe is not the best solution, but it works.